# Recursively ZIP a directory containing any number of files and subdirectories in Java?

Tags: java, file, directory, zip

Is there an easy way to recursively ZIP a directory that may or may not contain any number of files and any number of levels of subdirectories?

Comment: I checked Apache Commons Compress, and it's not there.  Odd; "make a zip file outta this directory" seems like pretty common functionality.

Comment: FYI: You can do it in DotNetZip with `ZipFile.AddDirectory();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Java API Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api)
and [How do you recursively traverse through file folders?](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/4123-how-do-you-recursively-traverse-through-file-folders.html).

Answer (score 12):

```
public final class ZipFileUtil {
    public static void zipDirectory(File dir, File zipFile) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);
        zipSubDirectory("", dir, zout);
        zout.close();
    }

    private static void zipSubDirectory(String basePath, File dir, ZipOutputStream zout) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                String path = basePath + file.getName() + "/";
                zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path));
                zipSubDirectory(path, file, zout);
                zout.closeEntry();
            } else {
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
                zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(basePath + file.getName()));
                int length;
                while ((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                zout.closeEntry();
                fin.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works well for me, but, for some mysterious reason, also adds files like 'java.io.FileInputStream@1c636e41' to the archive. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

I use the ZipFileSystem implementation in ruby with great success, though I've never used it in java.  You might want to check [this](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Library/Apache-commons-vfs-20070724-src/org/apache/commons/vfs/provider/zip/ZipFileSystem.java.java-doc.htm) out:

Comment: Link in answer is dead (404 Not Found).