# Modify an xml file inside zip file on android device

Tags: android, xml, zip

I have a zip file which contains some xml files. I want to modify some tags inside these xml files, is it possible with current android/ Java libraries ?

Example - test.zip contains - fileA.xml and fileB.xml.

My intention is to modify fileA.xml content and save it back to zip file.

I looked at ZipFile library, but it only allows me to read the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you can't just "edit" an entry in-place in a zip file is because it's compressed.

You'll need to decompress it, edit the files as needed, and then re-compress it.

Comment: I am getting zip entry for the file which i want to edit from zipfile, modifying it by creating a Document object from inputstream. Copying rest of the files to new zipfile, but am not sure how to create back a new zipentry from this document..any idea? Thanks

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403830/recursively-zip-a-directory-containing-any-number-of-files-and-subdirectories-in